# Direct Sum of vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

How is direct sum of two vector subspaces different from the sum of two vector subspaces i.e. how is $X\oplus Y$ different from $X + Y$, where $X, Y$ are subspaces.

Comment: For the direct sum, the intersection of $X$ and $Y$ must be trivial. That means every $v \in V$ (let $V$ be the ambient vector space) has a **unique** representation $v = x+y$ with $x\in X,\, y \in Y$. For the not-necessarily-direct sum, such a represenattion need not be unique.

Comment: It is the same with the additional constraint that $X\cap Y=0$

Comment: @DanielFischer can we say that sum of some vector subspaces is a necessary condition for the existence of direct sum of those two subspaces?

Comment: @Fazzolini I don't understand what you're asking, sorry. Whenever we have a collection of subspaces of a vector space, the sum of these subspaces is defined. So the existence of the sum of subspaces isn't a condition at all. The sum of two subspaces is direct, if and only if the two subspaces have trivial intersection.

Comment: @DanielFischer Suppose we have 3 subspaces in some space, namely, $U_1$, $U_2$ and $U_3$. Can we say that for some $V$ to be equal to direct sum of $U_1$, $U_2$ and $U_3$, the following two conditions should be met: (1) $V$ is the sum of $U_1$, $U_2$ and $U_3$ and (2) each element of $V$ can be written uniquely as $u_1 + u_2 + u_3$ where $u_1 \in U_1$,  $u_2 \in U_2$ and $u_3 \in U_3$?

Comment: @Fazzolini Yes, that is correct. Note that the uniqueness of the representation means $U_1 \cap (U_2 + U_3) = U_2 \cap (U_1 + U_3) = U_3 \cap (U_1 + U_2) = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For instance, in $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$
\langle e_1 \rangle + \langle e_2, e_3 \rangle = \langle e_1 \rangle \oplus \langle e_2, e_3 \rangle
$$

is a direct sum. Whereas

$$
\langle e_1, e_2 \rangle + \langle e_2, e_3 \rangle
$$

is not.

EDIT. $\langle e_1 \rangle $ stands for the vector subspace generated by vector $e_1 = (1,0,0)$. Maybe you write it $\mathrm{span}(e_1)$? The output of both sums is the same, namely the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The point is that the first sum is a *direct* one because $\langle e_1 \rangle \cap \langle e_2, e_3\rangle = \left\{ (0,0,0)\right\}$, whereas $\langle e_1,e_2 \rangle \cap \langle e_2, e_3 \rangle = \langle e_2\rangle$. Hence the last one is *not* a direct sum.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Thanks. I have understood the comment by Daniel but example by Agusti is still not clear.

Comment: Why is it not clear?

Comment: @ Agusti Sorry for the delayed response.But could you clarify what are $ \langle e_1 \rangle $ and $ \langle e_1,e_2 \rangle $ - are they just standard basis vectors or are they vector spaces. In either cases what is the output of the two summations illustrated?

Comment: @Hashtag. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @ Agusti Thanks. Got the point you were trying to make. But if the output of both sums is identical in all cases then why do we need to make a classification between direct sum and sum. Does it benefit in any way if its a direct sum ..or are the properties of a direct sum different?

Comment: It's a piece of information you add to your sum: knowing that $X \oplus Y = X + Y$ allows you, for instance, to get a basis of $X+Y$ "for free": you just put together a basis of $X$ and a basis for $Y$. Otherwise, if the sum is NOT direct, the union of a basis of both $X$ and $Y$ is NOT a basis of $X + Y$.