# What ring-sum of vector spaces can possibly mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

I'm given this test assignment, and I can't decipher what it says. Would you kindly help me?

Here's the assignment itself:

> Let $U$ and $W$ be sub-spaces of the linear vector space $V$ s.t. $U \oplus W = V$.  Let $S \subseteq U$ and $T \subseteq W$ be two finite linearly independent sets.  Prove that $S \cup T$ is linearly independent.

I don't think that ring-sum symbol here is actually the ring sum (xor, exclusive or).  Because, if it was, that would mean that either $V$ or $W$ didn't include the trivial (zero) subspace, which would disqualify them from being (sub-)spaces.

So, could you guess what could be meant by this symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the [direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum). That is

$$U \oplus W = \{u+ w ; u \in U  \ \ \text{and}\ \ w\in W \}$$

and $$U \cap W = \{0\}$$

Answer (score 2):

The symbol $\oplus$ denotes the **direct sum** of (here) vector spaces; in this context, as $U,W$ are said to be subspaces of $V$, it denotes the **internal direct sum**, i.e., $U\cap W=\{0\}$ and $U,W$ together span $V$.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $\oplus$ means direct sum. You can look at any linear algebra book for definition. Here is one link: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pskoufra/M115A-DirectSumOfVectorSpaces.pdf You can also see [Direct Sum of vector subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486476/direct-sum-of-vector-subspaces)